# How to delete contacts from the Windows 8 People app?

Tags: contacts, windows-8

I never really bothered to keep my Hotmail contact information up to date, so now that I connected it to Windows 8, suddenly I see all this outdated contact information or people I've long stopped talking to.

[image]

I don't see any buttons or options where I can click to delete someone.

So how do I clean up my Windows 8 People app and remove these contacts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the details of the contact you would like to delete, right click somewhere on the screen to open the app bar and `Delete` the contact.

Comment: How unintuitive, guess I should get used to right clicking then!

Comment: Maybe more intuitive with touch? How do you get the app-bar then for example?

Comment: @IvoFlipse Right-clicking is there since Windows 95.

Comment: You can delete contacts from People by bring up the contact then right click anywhere on the screen to bring up the option bar to delete the contact. This assumes you use a mouse. If you have a touch screen, you can do the same by swiping the bottom edge upward.