# How do I delete contacts from the Windows 8 people app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-people-app

My Windows 8 people app is showing many contacts which no longer exist in my Outlook/Hotmail contacts list.  How do I make them disappear from the people app?

If I close the app down, and relaunch it, it says 'synchronising' in the top left of the screen, but the contacts all remain.  I am not sure where these contacts are coming from, as they no longer exist in Outlook.com and there are no other linked accounts.

I have read and tried [Gene's answer to How to delete contacts from the Windows 8 People app?](https://superuser.com/a/462312). It suggests bringing up the options bar and clicking **Delete**, but my options bar does not have a delete button...

Comment: This has already been asked before: http://superuser.com/questions/462299/how-to-delete-contacts-from-the-windows-8-people-app?rq=1

Comment: The answers given in that question don't work for me. They are saying click the 'delete' button, but there is no delete button when I bring up the options panel on mine.

Comment: @Sugarat: I have voted to reopen your question, but please don't edit out the duplicate header manually. It will disappear by itself if the question gets reopened.

Comment: If you were to click on one of these contacts, directly below their picture (or picture placeholder) it should identify where they have come from (such as Hotmail/Facebook/Twitter/etc.) - what does it say for the contacts you are having issues with?

Comment: It does not say anything. There is a single button that says 'View Profile' to the right of the generic avatar picture, but that doesn't show anything either..  See http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=bccf5fa

Comment: What do you see when you right click to bring up the options?

Comment: Far left of the options is 'Home',  then on the far right of the screen I have 'Online Only'  and 'New Contact'.