# How to remove a contact from people app in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

How do I remove a contact from the people app in windows 8. If I right click on a contact it only gives me the option to edit contact but not to delete. Removing the name out of the box does not remove the contact either.

Comment: Refer to this question. http://superuser.com/questions/462299/how-to-delete-contacts-from-the-windows-8-people-app

Answer (score 0):

Click the contact to view details page and then right-click to get to the commands at the bottom, there is a delete command!